# Python Apache Beam: date value out of range

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Applying [this](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/game/game_stats.py) or [this](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/windowed_wordcount.py) example to build my program, each time I try to insert to Big Query, I have this error:

OverflowError: date value out of range [while running 'Format']

My Beam Pipeline is this:

```
Bigquery = (transformation
            | 'Format' >> beam.ParDo(FormatBigQueryoFn())
            | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(
            'XXXX',
            schema=TABLE_SCHEMA,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
        )))
```

In class FormatBigQueryoFn is where it should be the logic of the window data time

The code of exmple 1:

```
def timestamp2str(t, fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000'):
  """Converts a unix timestamp into a formatted string."""
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(t).strftime(fmt)

    class TeamScoresDict(beam.DoFn):
  """Formats the data into a dictionary of BigQuery columns with their values
  Receives a (team, score) pair, extracts the window start timestamp, and
  formats everything together into a dictionary. The dictionary is in the format
  {'bigquery_column': value}
  """

def process(self, team_score, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
    team, score = team_score
    start = timestamp2str(int(window.start))
    yield {
        'team': team,
        'total_score': score,
        'window_start': start,
        'processing_time': timestamp2str(int(time.time()))
}
```

The code of example 2:

```
class FormatDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
    ts_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f UTC'
    window_start = window.start.to_utc_datetime().strftime(ts_format)
    window_end = window.end.to_utc_datetime().strftime(ts_format)
    return [{'word': element[0],
             'count': element[1],
             'window_start':window_start,
'window_end':window_end}]
```

What could be wrong in my pipeline?

EDIT:

If I print, for example, the window.start i get:

```
Timestamp(-9223372036860)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was reading the data from a file before to test it with Google Pub/Sub.

While I was reading the data from a file the elements doesnt have timestamp.

Is a must to have a timestamp in your element.

Pub/Sub attach this timestamp automatically.

From [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#provided-windowing-functions):

*The simplest form of windowing is using fixed time windows: given a timestamped PCollection which might be continuously updating, each window might capture (for example) all elements with timestamps that fall into a five minute interval.*